# How can you compare a dictionary of list of tuples to each other?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, defaultdict

It's hard to describe the question without code. So here's what I need help with.

```
{'22': [('22_0',['A','B','C','D']),
      ('22_1',['B','C','D','E']),
      ('22_2',['A','B','C'])]


'33': [('33_0',['A','B','C','D']),
      ('33_1',['A','B','C','D']),
      ('33_2',['A','B','C','D'])]}


Should return [False, True], description below.
```

I want to iterate over defaultdict list items and return True if all the 2nd values of the nested tuples are equal to each other, otherwise False. There can be any number of nested tuples in the value lists.

The code for the dictionary above should return [False, True].

Any help would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: The order of keys in a dictionary is not fixed ... So I guess [False, True] and [True, False] are both valid answers, no?

Comment: I would have to fix the order somehow. The end goal is to eliminate the subcluster 33_0, 33_1, and 33_2 if they are all equal to each other and just keep parent cluster 33

Answer (score 1):

You can use all() with a list comprehension to check if all 2nd values in the tuples match the 2nd item in the first tuple.

```
d = {
    '22': [('22_0', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
           ('22_1', ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']),
           ('22_2', ['A', 'B', 'C'])],

    '33': [('33_0', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
           ('33_1', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
           ('33_2', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])]
}

result = []
for key, value in d.items():
    result.append((key, all([i[1] == value[0][1] for i in value])))
print(result)
```

In the result, I pair the boolean with the dictionary key it refers to, since dictionaries don't always access items in the order we expect:
`[('22', False), ('33', True)]`

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
import operator as op


d = {
    "22": [
        ("22_0", ["A", "B", "C", "D"]),
        ("22_1", ["B", "C", "D", "E"]),
        ("22_2", ["A", "B", "C"]),
    ],
    "33": [
         ("33_0", ["A", "B", "C", "D"]),
         ("33_1", ["A", "B", "C", "D"]),
         ("33_2", ["A", "B", "C", "D"]),
    ]
}
```

**Code**

```
def all_equal(seq):
    """Return True if all elements are equal."""
    return len(set(seq)) == 1


def get_items(seq, index=1):
    """Return nested elements at index."""
    idx = op.itemgetter(index)

    return [idx(x) for x in [idx(lst) for lst in seq]]
```

**Demo**

```
[all_equal(get_items(x)) for x in d.values()]
```

**Details**

A functional equivalent:

```
def idx_1(seq):
    """Return the element at index 1."""
    return seq[1]


get_items = lambda x: map(idx_1, map(idx_1, x))


second_vals = map(get_items, d.values())
list(map(all_equal, second_vals))
# [False, True]
```